# The dot values in the chart gets cutoff for all max values-highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this issue where the markers on the chart gets cutoff for any max value. shown below:
[image]

code:

```
   render () {
      
                var data = [
    
                { name:"Jan", y:200.9, score:2 },
                { name:"Feb", y: 200.5, score:1 },
                { name: "Mar", y:200.4, score:3 },
                { name: "Apr", y:200.4, score:5 },
                { name: "May", y:200.9, score:9},
                { name: "Jun", y:200.4, score:10 },
                { name: "Jun", y:200.4, score:7 }
              ]
                let maxValue= Math.max.apply(null, data.map((dot) => dot.y));
                 //im setting the yAxis in the chartConfig dynamically when data is rendered  
                  chartConfig.yAxis.max = maxValue;
              
     }
```

even when I set it to more than the max value from the data, i get the same clipped markers:

say ex:

```
chartConfig.yAxis.max = maxValue +100;
```

as you can see the 200 being the only and max value here, the markers are not displayed correctly. if I change the max 'y' value to be 500, then the rest will be displayed correctly, but one with values 500 would be cutoff..
I tried setting the `yAxis: {min:0,max:250}` does not work.

any ideas what might be the issue or how to solve it..Thanks!

note: I was referring this as an example, http://jsfiddle.net/KdHME/474/ it works here by adding the min max values to yAxis, but does nothing to mine..

Comment: can you explain a bit more what is problem in this http://jsfiddle.net/KdHME/475/

Comment: Markers are clipped because the plot area is clipped with the clip path - it does not take into account marker's radius or line width - you just need to set the max value a little higher than max data value. Anyway, If we do not see the code, it is guessing.

Comment: @morganfree: that worked when I set the value = 500, however im wondering is there any definite calculation that would allow to set a yAxis.max higher than the max value in an array??

Comment: @morganfree: so i tried something like: chartConfig.yAxis.max = maxValue +200; and it worked for me for this data, however when the values change and so does the maxValue in the array, this same config : chartConfig.yAxis.max = maxValue +200; does not work, it still cuts off certain part...any idea how to fix that?? Thanks!

Comment: You can use load event, and when the load fires, you can update your axis with a correct max. So in load event, you can do sth like this.yAxis[0].update({max: this.yAxis[0].max + someValue}) or use series max instead of the axis max

Comment: how can i define "someValue" ?